# python mysql problem using string as query

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-error-1064

So I'm at the point in my program where I have a string containing the query I want to use to insert a row into a database:

```
query = '"INSERT INTO new_test (test_name, IP, test_run_date, results_query_time, run_time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", ("new_test", "192.168.17.194", "143917160811", "12.4847829342", "46.1268320084")'
```

However, when I execute the command:

```
cursor.execute(query)
```

I get this error

> ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'"INSERT INTO new_test (test_name, IP, test_run_date, results_query_time, run_tim\' at line 1')

I tried a few other combinations of quotes but I can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong.
Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do not build the query using string manipulation.  You are opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks if any of the data comes from a user.  The Python DB API supports parametrized queries; use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra `"` at the beginning of the query. That will definitely break it. It looks like you wanted:

```py
# notice the extra ' around the %s
query = """INSERT INTO new_test 
              (test_name, IP, test_run_date, results_query_time, run_time) 
           VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')""" % \
           ("new_test", "192.168.17.194", "143917160811", 
           "12.4847829342", "46.1268320084")
```

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me nuts